# Append/push in seamless immutable js - react js

Tags: reactjs, reducers, seamless-immutable

In Reducer for initial state I am using a seamless-immutable.

```
export const INITIAL_STATE = Immutable({
  foo:[],

})




function orderReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log('reducer is runnig');

  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_MENU: {

      return state.foo.push("newData") // how to achive this <----
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

How do I to push new data into the foo?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with ImmutableJS you can use `new List()` that has a `push` method. [Here are the docs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/). There are a bunch of data sets with different APIs that always return immutable objects. You will need to start learning those.

However if you are looking for a familiar way to deal with immutability I'd recommend you to switch to **Immer**. It let's you use plain javascript to return immutable objects, so you don't need to learn any new APIs. Take a look here:

https://github.com/mweststrate/immer

I personally always use plain javascript with the spread operator. I find it comfortable, fast, without any extra libraries. Very verbose when you get use to the syntax:

```
const pushedArr = [...oldArray, newElement]
const mergedObj = {...objA, ...objB}
```

Now that you know some alternatives, find the way that fits you and your team the most.

Comment: I am using seamless-immutable. I am bit confused wether the seamless-immutable and immutablejs are same? but I couldn't find the any docs regarding seamless-immutable in immutablejs site.

Comment: They are different libraries with different APIs. Haven't tested it, personally. @SandeepKumar